# XML to csv in java using DOM

Tags: java, xml, csv, dom

I want to convert XML file to csv that is comma separate file for that i use DOM parser in java.

The output of below code is - AAA123456
The Desiered output is -**AAA,123,456**

This is what i develop so far.Hope i separate with node name as csv.

```
public class Main {

static public final String SEPARATOR = ",";

private static String decodeDetailOutputRecordXML(String str) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {

    str = "<a><b><c>AAA</c><d>123</d><e>456</e></b></a>";
```

Document doc =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes()));

```
    DocumentTraversal traversal = (DocumentTraversal) doc;
    NodeIterator iterator = traversal.createNodeIterator(doc.getDocumentElement(), NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, true);
    for (Node n = iterator.nextNode(); n != null; n = iterator.nextNode()) {
        out.println(n.getTextContent());

    }
    
    
    return "";
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    decodeDetailOutputRecordXML(null);
    return;
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you want to write low-level DOM code? The right tool for this job is XSLT. Or even XPath: with XPath 3.1 it can probably be done in a single XPath expression.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to demonstrate the DOM API usage to convert the XML format under consideration to CSV. The example code below used DOM API directly and [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to write the CSV file.

The Example XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
    <b>
        <c>Somedata0</c>
        <d>Somedata1</d>
        <e>Somedata2</e>
    </b>
    <b>
        <c>Xdata0</c>
        <d>Xdata1</d>
        <e>Xdata2</e>
    </b>
</a>
```

The routine that converts the XML to CSV

```
package org.test;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

public class XMLToCSVTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        
        String inputFilePath="D:\\workspaces\\mtplatform\\TechTest\\testfiles\\testdata.xml";
        String outputFilePath="D:\\workspaces\\mtplatform\\TechTest\\testfiles\\testdataOut.csv";
        
        /*
         * We assume that we know the structure and the column names of the CSV file
         */
        String[] csvHeaders=new String[] {"c","d","e"};
        
        /*
         * Using Xerces DOM parser directly, same can also be achieved through JAXP
         */
        DOMParser parser=new DOMParser();
        
        try(FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(inputFilePath);
            CSVWriter writer=new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(outputFilePath));){
            
            /*
             * Write the CSV headers
             */
            writer.writeNext(csvHeaders);
            
            InputSource source=new InputSource(fis);
            parser.parse(source);
            
            Element documentElement=parser.getDocument().getDocumentElement();
            
            /*
             * We assume that we know the structure of the XML completely and we also assume the data is actually there, that is 
             * no elements are missing being optional.
             */
            NodeList elementBList=documentElement.getElementsByTagName("b");
            for(int i=0;i<elementBList.getLength();i++) {
                
                Element elementB=(Element)elementBList.item(i);
                
                Element elementC=(Element)elementB.getElementsByTagName("c").item(0);
                Element elementD=(Element)elementB.getElementsByTagName("d").item(0);
                Element elementE=(Element)elementB.getElementsByTagName("e").item(0);
                
                String[] line=new String[] {elementC.getFirstChild().getNodeValue(),
                                            elementD.getFirstChild().getNodeValue(),
                                            elementE.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()};
                
                writer.writeNext(line);
                
            }//for closing
            
            writer.flush();
            
        }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    }//main closing

}//class closing
```

The CSV output

```
"c","d","e"
"Somedata0","Somedata1","Somedata2"
"Xdata0","Xdata1","Xdata2"
```

NOTE: The above is one way to convert an XML to CSV with DOM API directly. While direct DOM API gives lot of flexibility, it is also slightly complicated to use. XML being an hierarchical data could sometimes be difficult to express as CSV, which is a flat data structure without either some loss of fidelity or a more complicated CSV structure, a case in point is multiple occurrence of a specific child element (in general multi-value). The actual CSV output also could be written as part of the routine, however, it would be tedious and error prone, OpenCSV has been used for that reason.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But according to the file i have, some elements are added for next tag iteration.So difficult to use getElementsByTagName (large file).Example like,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
    <b>
        <c>Somedata0</c>
        <d>Somedata1</d>
        <e>Somedata2</e>
    </b>
    <b>
        <c>Xdata0</c>
        <d>Xdata1</d>
        <e>Xdata2</e><f> data3</f>
    </b>
</a>            Any solution for this?Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Michell, it is straight forward enough. The elementB.getElementsByTagName("X").item(0) will return null, if the element is not present. Retrieve all the elements and write the value for the ones not null and null for the ones null in the array of String.